# What is the definition of "occupant" in 14 CFR 91.307?

Tags: faa-regulations, parachute

Does a solo pilot performing aerobatics constitute an "occupant" for the purposes of requiring a parachute per [91.307(c)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=3efaad1b0a259d4e48f1150a34d1aa77&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10&idno=14#se14.2.91_1307)?

Comment: Are they occupying the aircraft?

Answer (score 1):

If you're solo you don't need a parachute (emphasis mine):

> Unless each occupant of the aircraft is wearing an approved parachute,
>   no pilot of a civil aircraft **carrying any person (other than a
>   crewmember)** may execute any intentional maneuver that exceeds [...]

Incidentally, 91.307 says nothing about aerobatics; that's in [91.303](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=3efaad1b0a259d4e48f1150a34d1aa77&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10&idno=14#se14.2.91_1303).

And [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/588/62) is closely related.